# Converting Date Formats in R - Strange format

Tags: r, datetime-format

I have an date column with dates like this

```
Mon Jun 29 13:28:37 BRT 2020
```

I would like to convert it to something like 29/06/2020.

How can i do this using R?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

`date<-Sys.time()`

`format(date, "%d/%m/%Y")`

The output of the call from "format" should look like:

"16/04/2021"

With uppercase lettres of the formatstring format the date into the long version of the year.

`format(date, "%d/%m/%y")` would result into:

"16/04/21"